# Search for parse user to return multiple results

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a `UITableViewController` and in it is a `UISearchBar` which searches for Parse.com Users. When I search for type "abc", I want all users with string "abc" not just the closets match.

.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFUser *foundUser;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFRelation *friendsRelation;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *allUsers;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFUser *currentUser;
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.searchBar.delegate = self;

}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
    [query orderByAscending:@"username"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        } else {
            self.allUsers = objects;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }];

    self.currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];

}

#pragma mark -search bar

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

    //dismiss keyboard and reload table
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

    //Enable the cancel button when the user touches the search field
    self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = TRUE;
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

    //disable the cancel button when the user ends editing
    self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = FALSE;
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

    //dismiss keyboard
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];

    //reset the foundUser property
    self.foundUser = nil;

    //Strip the whitespace off the end of the search text
    NSString *searchText = [self.searchBar.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    searchText = [searchText lowercaseString];

    //Check to make sure the field isnt empty and Query parse for username in the text field
    if (![searchText isEqualToString:@""]) {

        PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
        [query whereKey:@"username" containsString:searchText];
        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {

                //check to make sure the query actually found a user
                if (objects.count > 0) {

                    //set your foundUser property to the user that was found by the query (we use last object since its an array)
                    self.foundUser = objects.lastObject;

                    //The query was succesful but returned no results. A user was not found, display error message
                } else {

                }

                //reload the tableView after the user searches
                [self.tableView reloadData];

            } else {

                //error occurred with query

            }

        }];

    }
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    // Return the number of sections.
    if (self.foundUser) {

        return 1;

    } else {

        return 0;
    }

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    if (self.foundUser) {

        return 1;

    } else {

        return 0;
    }

}
```

How can I search for a string and retrieve all users with that string?

Comment: Your search is correct. Be aware though that the search is case sensitive so  a searchText of "abc" will not match a username containing "Abc". Have you debugged and seen how many objects are in the "objects" array?

Comment: Yes, but what i want is if i type `A` i want to see all users with the letter `A`

Comment: Why run a parse query at all?  Aren't all of the users (allUsers) available locally after viewDidAppear?

Comment: Yes, but i have a search bar instead that only shows users after search, but when i type a letter i want users with that letter. i dont want all users showing @danh

Comment: @danh or i want to show more than one user to display when i press search at the moment one user displays when i type letters that multiple usernames contain.

Comment: Right, like a normal search bar behavior.  You need a second array that holds search results, and the table view datasource needs to show that array while search is active.  You fill that array with users that match the search criterion.  But you don't need a parse query to do the match.  The users are already there, just find the matching subset *locally* and put that in a results array

Comment: @danh im new to development can you please kindly help in go in the right direction.

Comment: Getting all users in viewDidAppear and then searching locally is not scalable. Parse will never return more than 1000 user anyway, and even this is too many for your app to be fast and responsive. You would need to fire queries for every letter instead, which is also not good design for a mobile app. If fetching usernames on the fly in an AJAX-like manner is what you want, you will have to create a workaround. But I really can't see how this is a very useful function for usernames...

Comment: @LonelyPenguin ok, at the moment when i search a username it returns one result containing the search text even if search text does not match the username. how can i return multiple users which all contain the search text? can you help with that?

Comment: You have two searches. The one in viewDidAppear gets ALL users, sorted by username. Your other search should retrieve all users with a username that *contains* your search string. You set foundUser to "lastObject", so you are at the moment disregarding all other users in your code. But they should all be in the "objects" array.

Comment: @LonelyPenguin ok but `self.foundUser` is a `PFObject` and i get warning if i say `self.foundUser = objects` as its incompatible to point NSArray to PFobject

Comment: Yes. But you need to do something with the returned objects. What do you need them for? If the search returns 3 objects, what will you do with them? Most likely, you need to change your self.foundUser to an array and call it foundUsers instead. Then you can use this array for i.e. displaying a list of matching users or something.

Comment: @LonelyPenguin thanks i did that and it works now :)